# Excel - repeat parts of formula x-times

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to repeat a formula for x-times depending on a number shown in a different cell. For me, this number is the length of a given text.

What I am trying to do is to add character(s) before and after each given character, to have a new text in a new cell.

The basic part of the original formula - that I want to shorten because the original text has now a length of ~100 characters; so I would have to repeat this basic part of the formula 100 times - looks like this:

```
=$T$10&MID(K21;1;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;2;1)&$T$12
```

Now in a different cell, I have the number 33 (the length of the original text). Now the part

```
$T$11&MID(K21;2;1)
```

should be repeated 32 times but the number in the middle (giving the position) should iterate accordingly. If you type the formula manually for this example it would look like this:

```
=$T$10&MID(K21;1;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;2;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;3;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;4;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;5;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;6;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;7;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;8;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;9;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;10;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;11;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;12;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;13;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;14;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;15;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;16;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;17;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;18;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;19;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;20;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;21;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;22;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;23;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;24;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;25;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;26;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;27;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;28;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;29;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;30;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;31;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;32;1)&$T$11&MID(K21;33;1)&$T$12
```

Is there any possibility to dynamically generate this formula according to the number given in a different cell?

For several reasons in the workflow, I do not want to use a VBA macro here.

Comment: I'm almost sure there is no way for that. You may find a workaround by using latest version of Excel (see new CONCAT function there) and splitting the content of your current K21 to one character per cell.

Comment: Could you describe what that function is actually supposed to do and maybe give an example how it would look with two or three repetitions instead of 33? That way it would be clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: It can be done only if you have the latest version of Excel that has  TEXTJOIN.  If you do not have access to that then vba is the only way.

Comment: Though It can be done in **Google Sheets**: `=$T$10 & ArrayFormula(JOIN($T$11,MID(K21,ROW(INDIRECT("1:" & A2)),1)))` where A2 is the number of repeats.

Comment: @Seth The change of text I am trying to do is to reformat text from
`P12,R12`
to
`CP,C1,C2,CR,C1,C2,`
So every Character in the first cell gets a C befor and a comma afterwards.I hope this helps.

Comment: @Scott Crane: I will check if I have TEXTJOIN or if I can use Google sheets for this workflow and will let you know. At least it is a good starting point, to have a look at. Thank you!

Comment: Why are you not just using the `REPLACE` or [`SUBSITUTE`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944e-a904-4336-a9b0-1e58df3bc332) functions for this? I don't really get what the layout of the tables should be and what kind of transformation should be taking place so this might not be applicable but it sounds like a more direct approach.

Comment: Well I think for `REPLACE` and `SUBSTITUTE` you would 1. need wildcards or something because you don't know the characters beforehand and 2. for

Comment: @Seth Well I think for `REPLACE` and `SUBSTITUTE` you would 1. need wildcards or something because you don't know the characters beforehand and 2. at least for `SUBSTITUTE` you would also need the position or n-th appearance of the character to substitute, no? I have not tried to create a formula with these two, but my feeling tells me, that this is more complicated than what I have now??? But you are welcome to prove it different to me. My current solution works fine though.Thanks.

Comment: As the documentation page says the `instance_num` is an optional parameter for `SUBSITUTE`. As an example `SUBSITUTE('ACACAC','A','C')` would result in `CCCCCC`. The German Name would be `WECHSELN`. But after reading your example again, this probably wouldn't help. It would've been nice to have the example input and output in the actual question but it's nice that you found an answer and posted it.

Comment: @Seth under point number 9. of my answer you can see the original and the resulting text. If you like the answer I'd be happy to receive my first vote. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say I have found a solution to my challenge. I am using Excel 2013 and this is my solution:

1. Activate iterations in Excel with X (e.g 150) iterations: Go to 'File' --> 'Options' --> 'Formula' and activate iterations
2. This is the given text:

   `B2=P50,R50,P1,R1,P27,R27,`
3. This is the iteration formula:

German    `B3=WENN(B3<150;B3+1;1)`

English   `B3=IF(B3<150,B3+1,1)`

Activate this cell and press enter to assure that the iteration result is X=150 or 1. Other results may occur if several recalculations have taken place shortly after each other. So one iteration process has been interrupted with the next one.

4. This is the iteration formula minus 3:

   `B4=B3-3`
5. These are the characters  that are inserted before each character of the given text:

   `B5=C`
6. These are the characters that are inserted after each character of the given text:

   `B6=,`
7. This is the formula to have the characters before and after each of the original characters:

German    `B7==WENN($B$4<0;B7;WENN($B$4=0;"";WENN(LÄNGE(B7)<(LÄNGE(B2))*(LÄNGE(B5)+LÄNGE(B6)+1);VERKETTEN(B7;$B$5;TEIL(B2;$B$4;1);$B$6);B7)))`

English   `B7==IF($B$4<0,B7,IF($B$4=0,"",IF(LEN(B7)<(LEN(B2))*(LEN(B5)+LEN(B6)+1),CONCATENATE(B7,$B$5,MID(B2,$B$4,1),$B$6),B7)))`

8. Just make sure that the resulting iteration formula rests at X=150 or 1 after the iteration process. You can achieve this by clicking into the cell of the iteration formula, with your cursor visible behind the formula, and then press enter
9. This is the original and the resulting text:

   `P50,R50,P1,R1,P27,R27,`

   `CP,C5,C0,C,,CR,C5,C0,C,,CP,C1,C,,CR,C1,C,,CP,C2,C7,C,,CR,C2,C7,C,,`

If you like this or this is new to you, please vote for the answer. 
Thank you.